# What is empty session path in tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, webserver, tomcat6, connector

I have read apache tomcat documentation a day before, and I am so confused about `emptySessionPath` . Up to my knowledge, if it's set to true, the `emptySessionPath` is stored at the root folder of web application. Please give the right definition of the term  `emptySessionPath` and what happens if it is set to true and false?

Please guide me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `emptySessionPath` field just states whether the all cookie should be stored in the root URL path `/` (if `emptySessionPath=true`) or not (otherwise).

This is used by Apache's Connector. See details [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/ajp.html) (This is for AJP Connector, which is part of the Connnector object).

What this basically means is:

> If `emptySessionPath` is enabled in
>   tomcat, the `JSESSIONID` cookie is 
>   written to the root "/" path.  This
>   means that whatever webapp you are  on
>   will use the same cookie.  Each webapp
>   will re-write the cookie's  value to
>   hold that webapp's session id, and
>   they are all different.
>
> When this is enabled and servlets in
>   different webapps are used,  requests
>   from the same user to different
>   servlets will end up  overwriting the
>   cookie so that when the servlet is
>   again interacted  with it will create
>   a new session and loose the session it
>   had already  set up.
>
> If `emptySessionPath` is not set, there
>   are multiple cookies in the  browser,
>   one for each webapp (none at the
>   root), so different webapps  are not
>   re-writing each other's cookie as
>   above.

`JSESSIONID` is the ID Session for your Webapp. See a full explanation [here](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/portals-pluto-dev/200502.mbox/%3Ca2519328f3ba1d1eddfc33c924b6805d@umich.edu%3E).

*Update: This information about **usage** is somewhat outdated - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9441231/150740) for a more up-to-date information on how to set the Session path also for recent tomcat.*

Comment: Hi elite,Please explain further more what happened if emptysessionpath is not set?

Comment: @Muneeswaran Balasubramanian, if you read my first link, the default value is `false` if not set. Also, read the last paragraph on the blocked section, it explains if `emptySessionPath` is not set.

Comment: ya.i can't understand your last paragraph on the blocked section,so only i ask to u.please explain further more.

Comment: In my application,i have send the request after session expired.If that request is http request that works fine.But if that request is Ajax request,the url is changed but the page is not loaded.But after i set the emptysessionpath is true.All works well.SO what happens between this?If you can please explain.

Comment: Ajax won't reload the page since you're doing an asynchronous call to the server hence why it never reload the page. I can't really explain why everything works well when `emptySessionPath` is set.

Answer (score 5):

If emptySessionPath is set to true, it will eliminate the context path from JSESSIONID cookie.It will set a cookie path to /.This attribute can be used for cross application  autehentication mechanism.

Answer (score 4):

Session are, as you probably know, often maintained by a cookie. A cookie has two values that determines whether they should be returned by the browser for a certain request, *cookieDomain* and *cookiePath*. The *cookiePath* must match that of the request.

A request is made for

```
 /some/request/for/this.html
```

Cookie would be returned with cookie path:

```
 / 
 /some
 /some/request
```

But not for cookie path:

```
 /other
```

By spec, a session is not shared between different web applications, so if you have web application `foo.war` deployed under `/foo`, the session cookie path would, by default be set to `/foo`.

It seems [Connector.emptySessionPath](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/connector/Connector.html#emptySessionPath) is a protected variable on Connector. I haven't read the code - but I guess it has something to do with Tomcat's single sign on or sharing sessions, where you login to one context and are authenticated in all - in which case the cookie path must be `/` for the session cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, for the web_app version 3.0, the cookie configuration is standarized, so the equivalent to the AJP's emptySessionPath in webapp 3.0 is:

<session-config>
    <cookie-config>
      <path>/</path>
      <secure>true</secure>
    </cookie-config>
  </session-config>