# Share Session between war applications in the same ear Jboss7

Tags: java, session, jboss7.x, share

Good afternoon in my timezone.

After deploying my ear application i notice that the session is not share between war application inside the same ear.
Where can i configure this issue ?

Thanks in advance.
Best regards.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9441231/13075). It seems the option to share sessions between Contexts have become part of the Servlet 3.0 spec.