# Is it possible to share the session data between two virtual hosts in tomcat7?

Tags: apache, session, tomcat7, subdomain

I have two virtual hosts in server.xml of tomcat 7

```
<Host name="www.mydomain.com" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
    <Context path="" docBase="MyApp1" />
</Host>

<Host name="sub.mydomain.com" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
    <Context path="" docBase="MyApp2" />
</Host>
```

Is there a way to share the session data between them? e.g. Users logged in MyApp1 does not need to login again when they open MyApp2.

Comment: i think this discussion here ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436736/sharing-session-data-between-contexts-in-tomcat ) can point you in the right way