# How do I prevent Jetty/GAE from creating new sessions for different context paths?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, session, jetty

I have an application hosted and it uses many different servlet paths. It seems Jetty (that GAE uses) creates a new session for every context path in the request URL.

Example:

1. abc.appspot.com/
2. abc.appspot.com/path2/hello

Each of those paths use two different sessions. Is there any way to prevent that? I came across the following config that can be used in the web.xml file for Jetty servers:

`<context-param>
      <param-name>org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.SessionPath</param-name>
      <param-value>/</param-value>
</context-param>`

It hasn't worked for me, am I doing it wrong or this is impossible? I've heard [this is possible in Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9441231/1668384).

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want to share a session (data) between 2 applications and not just share the same id with different id.

If so, check spring-session which is server agnostic, and can help you to do crazy stuff

Comment: I read the docs and it tells me we need to install Redis in the local system and run it on a port to enable Spring Session. I don't think that's possible in a standard Google App Engine environment.

Comment: I think it is possible. You can also use a standard DB to store your session. There is a lot of option.

Comment: GAE is a PaaS where programmers don't have access to the file system. Could you point me to a link in GAE docs that shows how this is possible?

Comment: You have an application without a DB / data storage ? Use the same thing for the session.