# Architeturing JSP/Servlet solution with multiple Frontend

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I'm currently working on a Servlet/JSP platform but I would need to be able to manage multiple frontend (different look and feel and features) with only one unique backend.
I tried to manage frontend and backend in two different war files on the same tomcat instance but I'm facing issues on the session sharing (refer the question [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50516010/troubles-with-httpsession-with-2-different-requests#50516119)).

I would like to find an architecture which provides me a way to simplify the deployment and avoid having one single and huge WAR File to be deployed. Typically if I want to add a new front end look and feel, I would like to be able to avoid a service disruption on the backend side and manage my developments independently for each part of the solution.

Do you have any architecture proposal that I can follow ?

Comment: If your problem is the session with two wars using the same tomcat, you may be able to workaround that by changing the jsession cookie name of one of them.

Comment: Did you have a look at the [Single Sign On Valve](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/valve.html#Single_Sign_On_Valve) ?