# How to change Grails Spring Security Cookie Path

Tags: grails, cookies, spring-security, remember-me, cookie-path

I've got two grails applications using spring security:

- Core
- Module (user and role tables mapping to Core db tables)

I want to have a single sign on functionality using "remember me". The problem is that the cookies are stored in different paths "/Core" and "/Module" which I'm guessing is the reason why it isn't working.

Does anyone know how to change the cookie path to be "/"?

**Notes**:

- Do I need to make a change in Spring Security or the Tomcat server configuration (using intellij)
- I want to avoid setting up a CAS server if possible
- I'm looking into plugins as an alternative

Thanks any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: For tomcat: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4332334/what-is-empty-session-path-in-tomcat

Comment: I had a similar problem - look at my solution here: [Solution with `HttpServletResponseWrapper`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41117823/7095884)

Comment: I had a similar problem - look at my solution [with an HttpServletResponseWrapper](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41117823/7095884)

Comment: I had a similar problem - look at my solution [with an HttpServletResponseWrapper](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41117823/7095884)

Answer (score 1):

When the remember-me filter creates the remember-me cookie, it sets the cookie path to the context path obtained from the request object (see related [source code here](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/rememberme/AbstractRememberMeServices.java#L363-L366)). If you want to customize this behavior, you'll need to override the `setCookie()` and `cancelCookie()` methods of the remember-me service implementation your application uses (either `TokenBasedRememberMeServices` or `PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices`) in a subclass, and configure the `RememberMeAuthenticationFilter` to use your custom implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I impltemented it.
 create a new service with extends **TokenBasedRememberMeServices** 
  override **setCookie** and **cancelCookie** method to set cookie path.
  Add cookiePath variable and add method to **setCookepath**()

Update resources.groovy

> ```
> rememberMeServices(YourTokenBasedRememberMeServices) { 
>     userDetailsService = ref("userDetailsService")
>     key = conf.rememberMe.key
>     cookieName = conf.rememberMe.cookieName
>     alwaysRemember = conf.rememberMe.alwaysRemember
>     tokenValiditySeconds = conf.rememberMe.tokenValiditySeconds
>     cookiePath = some config variable 
> }
> ```